# i am getting httpresponse exception : unauthorised for the twitter application + oauth.. how to solve it?

Tags: android, twitter, oauth

please help me. i need a code that will tweet using oauth + twitter api...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25o0b2aEw0E

i have used this project and i m getting error

08-25 11:47:32.747: WARN/System.err(2029): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Unauthorized
08-25 11:47:32.747: WARN/System.err(2029):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
08-25 11:47:32.747: WARN/System.err(2029):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at com.test.twitter.BLOA$PostTask.doInBackground(BLOA.java:336)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at com.test.twitter.BLOA$PostTask.doInBackground(BLOA.java:1)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:256)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:122)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:648)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:673)
08-25 11:47:32.756: WARN/System.err(2029):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)

and i want to solve that error while i m posting tweet.. pls help
thanks and regards...

Comment: Hello! Please, be more specific

Comment: Yes ! Please, be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/creating-a-twitter-oauth-application/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-users-with-twitter-oauth/